# Creating a safe filename from an NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsstring

Is there way to take a NSString and turn it into a safe version that can be used as a filename to save to the user Documents directory on the iPhone.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
NSString *inputString = @"This is sample text which may have funny chars and spaces in.";

NSInteger len = [inputString length];        
NSString *newFilename = [[inputString substringToIndex:MIN(20, len)] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"];
```

This currently leaves me with something like:

```
This is sample text .txt
```

Need to make sure characters that are not allowed in filenames and stripped out too.

Comment: I want this question re-opened. The duplicate question you are referring to does not have an accepted answer because none of the answers supplied answer the question correctly.

Comment: I re-opened this. The duplicate cited has not been active since September 2010 (asked in '09), has no accepted answer and no recent activity to speak of. In this case, it's just blocking another perfectly good question. It is likely that the duplicate, in this case might be better merged with this, where an accepted answer is likely to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably end up with some regex or something. Simply because it's too dangerous to use a `except`-filter (you may miss some illegal chars).

Therefor I'ld recommend you to use RegexKitLite (http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/), combined with the following line of code:

```
inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfRegex:@"([^A-Za-z0-9]*)" withString:@""];
```

This will replace all characters except A-Z, a-z and 0-9 =)!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it the old fashioned way instead of using a regex:

```
NSString* SanitizeFilename(NSString* filename)
{
    NSMutableString* stripped = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:filename.length];
    for (int t = 0; t < filename.length; ++t)
    {
        unichar c = [filename characterAtIndex:t];

        // Only allow a-z, A-Z, 0-9, space, -
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') 
        ||  (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == ' ' || c == '-')
            [stripped appendFormat:@"%c", c];
        else
            [stripped appendString:@"_"];
    }

    // No empty spaces at the beginning or end of the path name (also no dots
    // at the end); that messes up the Windows file system.
    return [stripped stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you really need is a safely random filename then just use SecRandomCopyBytes to the length you want and base64-encode it.

Comment: Sorry Chris, but base 64 does have e.g. the '+', '/' and possibly the '=' characters in it, so that's not a (complete) solution. Hex might do the work though.

Comment: I just keep generating random bytes and encode until I get one with neither character.  It's never taken more than one extra loop.

Comment: That's a bit weird too, you might just pick a random between 0..61 and then pick out a base 64 character without the / or + character, but I don't think the asker was aiming for an all random file name.